# Warn users when they are about to hit the "guaranteed" flag ban

Tags: feature-request, flags, declined-flags, flag-ban

Background: [Guaranteed flag-ban after a series of helpful flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243600/336163)

I've hit the "guaranteed" ban above more times than I should, the last time being just a few days ago.

Shog9 ♦ mentioned [above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243601/336163), in the context of adjusting the actual ban logic, that "Realistically, I'm not sure this is worth optimizing for". Instead of programming away this case, could we provide some sort of *warning* to users that are about to trip it? Right now, the [existing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/336163) warnings don't cover this case - that is, the user goes straight from "everything looks ok, no warnings" to *banned*, with nothing in between.

Let's add a warning on the flag dialog that lets a user know that the are about to hit the "guaranteed" ban. The warning would most likely trigger based on the following criteria:

- The user has had at least three non-comment flags *declined* in the past seven days.
- The total number of non-comment flags handled in the past seven days (regardless of disposition) plus the number of non-comment flags still outstanding is eight or above (when the number reaches 10, they are in danger of the automated ban regardless of whether their most recent flags were *helpful*).

The actual warning text could look something like this:

> Warning: Several of your flags have been declined in the previous week. Continuing to raise flags places you in danger of a flag ban, even if the flags are deemed *helpful*. Please see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243600/336163) post for more information.

This is not a duplicate of [Flawed question-ban system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337507) because this question is about flag bans and the other is about question bans.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flawed question-ban system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337507/flawed-question-ban-system)

Comment: @Rob totally different ban system. The OP is talking about *flagging* here, not asking questions or posting answers.

Answer (score 6):

You're quoting Shog:

> Realistically, I'm not sure this is worth optimizing for.

But they also said something quite interesting before that:

> For starters, there's no requirement that moderators process your flags in order - if your lousy flags were processed last, you'd still end up flag-banned.

Your flags are processed *asynchronously* in *unspecified order*, so you cannot reliably expect a helpful flag to compensate for a declined one.

And even if Shog's proposed solution was implemented in addition to yours, you would still not see the warning if you raised, say, three flags in a short while and all of them were later declined.

Comment: I agree that what the OP proposes is not a total solution, but at least it would improve the users' situation, that is, banned from raising flags. IMO, SO, Inc. should pay more efforts to solve/improve their system issues other than worrying about the so-called inclusiveness issue.